# sql server aspnet.identity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, model-view-controller, identity

Evenin' all.

Trying to remove EF from MVC/c# project.  I'm just not happy with the performance compared to straight sql -> Ado.net.

But want to keep the aspnet.identity.   Anyone know if there's something like  Microsoft.aspnet.identity.sqlserver?

I've web searched and checked nuget.  I know it won't have Microsoft.aspnet.identity.sqlserver per se, and there's lots of options, I'm not sure if the simple.data version is what I'm looking for or not.

Comment: I'd really be interesting in knowing what the performance difference is that you're seeing.  Do you have some measurements that you can share?

Comment: HI Brendan,  It would be better if you didn't rely on my tests.  Here's a link to Dapper.  It's its in use here at SO btw.  I'm not going to use Dapper, but there's comparisons between hand coded sql, Dapper and EF.  If you look down the link here there's some performance analysis.  It's very similar to what I've been seeing.  I say don't use mine a) I'm not a guru, b) my tests are very well controlled.   https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: pardon the inadvertent ego there.  I meant to say.  b) my tests are NOT very well controlled.

Comment: Also not sure how entity framework is slower than straight SQL... are you sure the queries cannot be rewritten to be made faster? are you lazy loading everything?

Comment: @krilovich it will be slower due to the overhead of things like object tracking, and the fact that the SQL generated by the framework is likely to be very different compared to what you'd write.  Whether or not that overhead is acceptable in your application is really what this question is about.

Comment: EF has to be slower than ADO.net.  a) it's a layer on top of ADO.net so the extra processing adds time to the calls.  b) the queries are not as  optimized as those I can write.  Any single call is not going to be noticeably slower to the user.  (Though in some worst case instances I've seen EF in the 800-900ms range and straight sql in the 10-15ms range.)   However, in aggregate the additional server load is going to cause over all performance to degrade, causing a need to consider web  server(where the ef layer is) and db server (where the poorly optimized queries are being executed)...

Comment: ... upgrades much earlier than expected.

Comment: I have to admit after looking the performance of Dapper and how easy it is to use, I have gone a head and instrumented my code with it.   GREAT!

Answer (score 0):

There is a reasonable write up on migrating a website to ASP.NET Identity on the asp.net site. It is entitiled "[Migrating an Existing Website from SQL Membership to ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity)" by Suhas Joshi and Rick Anderson (just noting this down in case the link is broken at any point and someone else needs to search for these details).

The article does specify NuGet packages and has step by step instructions on how to go about it. Hopefully this is of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually going from the old sql membership to identity.entityframework.   My task is to go from identity.entityframework to a non entityframework version.